# Calling a PROC in cursor

Tags: sql-server, cursor, procedure

I have table called `my_table` with this schema:

```
+----+--------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| ID | name (4 possible values) |  action (2 possible values) | sequence (1,2...n) |
+----+--------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to create a stored procedure that can process the data according to the sequence from the `sequence` column. This stored procedure should look at the value in `sequence` then execute the corresponding stored procedure. Current I have 8 separate stored procedures.

For example, if `seq = 1` then stored procedure #1 should be executed.
If `seq = 2` it goes to stored procedure #4 depending on the values of `name` and `action`. There are 8 possible matches.

Here's my attempt:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @name varchar(20), @action varchar(20), @ID int, @Seq varchar(20)
DECLARE ILOOP CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, Name, Action, Seq FROM my_table
OPEN ILOOP
FETCH NEXT FROM iloop INTO @ID, @name, @Action, @Seq
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT * From my_table WHERE Name = case Name when 'provider'
    then EXEC sp1
END
CLOSE ILOOP
DEALLOCATE ILOOP 
RETURN
```

Comment: Why, if seq = 2, does it not go to stored procedure 2?

Comment: no, not necessarily , it depends on name and action column. say it will go to proc2 only when name = c and action = Y.

Comment: So are you trying to figure out your calling logic, or how to make the stored procedure call itself?

Answer (score 1):

You have neglected to tell us anything about the specific logic used to select the stored procedures or what parameters they take but it seems you need something along these lines.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20) ,
    @Action VARCHAR(20) ,
    @ID INT ,
    @Seq VARCHAR(20)

DECLARE ILOOP CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  ID ,
            Name ,
            Action ,
            Seq
    FROM    my_table
    ORDER BY Seq

OPEN ILOOP
FETCH NEXT FROM ILOOP INTO @ID, @Name, @Action, @Seq
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 
    BEGIN
        IF @Name = 'A'
            AND @Action = 'X' 
            EXEC sp1 @Action, @ID, @Name
        ELSE 
            IF @Name = 'C'
                AND @Action = 'Y' 
                EXEC sp2 @Action, @ID, @Name

        FETCH NEXT FROM ILOOP INTO @ID, @Name, @Action, @Seq    
    END
CLOSE ILOOP
DEALLOCATE ILOOP
```

Comment: It should process by sequence order and call different procedures (any out of 8) according to column name & action. so start from seq 1, if name = a and action = X then call proc1.   If name = C and action = Y then call proc 2 and so onn... total of 8 possible cases..

Comment: OK that just needs an `ORDER BY` on the select and a change in the boolean conditions then. See edited answer.